# Asp.Net Server-side Output Cache gets hit every request (HttpHandler)

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, server-side

I have this pretty straight forward piece of code below.

There are several things I've tried and I can't understand why the server-side output cache is not working at http://localhost. Below is the last try of 'cache settings' in order to **not** see a HIT on the Debug output pane.

It's driving me nuts! How do I prevent the HIT...?! When I open the Developer tools and check Disable cache I'm expecting a cached server-side copy and not see a HIT in the Debug output pane.

I'm on Windows 8, but even on another Windows version (/IIS Version), I can't imagine the eventual code would be different.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MyHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("HIT"+DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

            context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5));
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
            context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
            context.Response.Cache.SetOmitVaryStar(true);
            context.Response.Cache.VaryByParams["none"] = true;
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

            // Just here for testing purposes
            const string url = "http://otherserver/image.png";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var task = client.GetStreamAsync(url);
                task.Wait();
                task.Result.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
                context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` is causing the pain in my situation. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest(v=vs.110).aspx) it:

> Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

This is the [Asp.Net pipeline flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

[image: Asp.Net pipeline flow]

The Handler is being executed somewhere in the middle as you can see and after calling `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` it skips everything and goes directly to Send request (or `CompleteRequest()` internally).

When this happens it also skips the "Update cache" events. This is where the Request Cache gets updated; where the Server-side output cache items will be added...

So, be aware of what `ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` does when you think you're done in your `HttpHandler`!

Another interesting read: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/May/21/Dont-use-ResponseEnd-with-OutputCache

Happy caching!